# Does it matter if I use RowDataBound or DataBound for a GridView

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

According to the VS 2008 properties for a GridView:

- DataBound fires after the control has been databound.
- RowDataBound fires after a row has been databound.

If I want to manipulate the text in a header column, does it matter if I use the DataBound or RowDataBound because I can always just check the e.Row.RowType.  Is there an actual difference besides the obvious?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

DataBound happens after all RowDataBound events are done firing, and therefore only fires once for the control. If you only have one thing to do, put it in the DataBound method. If it's something that needs to happen on an arbitrary row, do it in RowDataBound.

Comment: Ah.  It makes more sense now that you mentioned it like that.

Comment: That does not make sense "DataBound happens after each and every RowDataBound event is fired", yet you say it only fires once? Does it fire once before rowdatabound is fired or does it fire everytime? If the later then it does not happen just once.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking to customize something within a single **row**.  I'd use RowDataBound.

Answer (score 0):

**RowDataBound** event fires after the datafield that is rows in the backend's table bound with the datarows in the gridview.

Now we have all the data available in a grid (front end). We can manipulate or customize our grid on the basis of that data in **RowDataBound** event.

Means, what evercode we need to write for customization (like color change etc.) can be written in **RowDataBound** event.